# Global case insensitive regex matching for bot framework composer intents?

Tags: bot-framework-composer

In javascript the regex would be something like `/word/gi` how do i do the equivalent in botframework composer regex intent recognizer?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer it here

example : booka flight to (?**<>.***)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-define-triggers#intent-recognized